# teradata sas error ABORT SESSION command unknown reason

Tags: sas, teradata

I am getting the below error message and I cannot figure out why. Any advice on how to avoid this error is much preferred. I have received this error message three times today. I am thinking that I may have to get the ACCT_DIM_NB first and then run the query. Thanks

```
ERROR: Teradata row not delivered (trget): The request was aborted by an ABORT SESSION command.
```

Code used below.

```
    SELECT 
    A.ACCT_DIM_NB,
    C.ACCT_NB,
    B.CS_TXN_CD,
    A.TXN_AM,
    A.DAY_TIME_DIM_NB,
    A.TXN_DESCRIPTION
FROM ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_FCT_TXN AS A
INNER JOIN ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_DIM_TXN AS B
ON A.TXN_DIM_NB=B.TXN_DIM_NB

INNER JOIN ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_DIM_ACCT_DTL AS C
ON A.ACCT_DIM_NB=C.ACCT_DIM_NB
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT ACCT_NB FROM myid.temptable1) D
    ON CAST(C.ACCT_NB AS BIGINT) = CAST(D.ACCT_NB AS BIGINT)
WHERE B.CS_TXN_CD IN ('387','388','389','390')
AND A.DAY_TIME_DIM_NB GE '2013-01-01'
AND A.TIME_DIM_NB BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2050-01-01'
AND INDEX(UPPER(TXN_DESCRIPTION),'REVERSAL:')=0
```

Comment: do you have teradara sql assistant handy

Comment: Yes I have teradata sql assistant handy

Comment: try to run explain plan on this and see what it suggest. all i you need to do is add explain to your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your queries is taking lot of spool and being aborted by admin.  Try contacting your teradata admin regarding the same or break the query into small pieces and optimize it.

Comment: Would dividing the number of accounts by two save spool? For example, currently 3k accounts are uploaded to teradata. If I divided this by two, would this save spool space?

Comment: do not change anything to code other than breaking at inner join for example include till INNER JOIN ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_DIM_TXN AS B
ON A.TXN_DIM_NB=B.TXN_DIM_NB

INNER JOIN ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_DIM_ACCT_DTL AS C
ON A.ACCT_DIM_NB=C.ACCT_DIM_NB.  and also check whether you are not doing many to many joins

Answer (score 0):

```
       1) First, we lock myid.CB9019388E1 for access, we lock
         ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.acct in view ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_FCT_TXN for access,
         we lock ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn in view ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_FCT_TXN for
         access, we lock ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.DDM_DIM_ACCT_DTL in view
         ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_DIM_ACCT_DTL for access, and we lock
         ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.DDM_DIM_TXN in view ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_DIM_TXN for
         access.## Heading ##
      2) Next, we do an all-AMPs SUM step to aggregate from
         myid.CB9019388E1 by way of an all-rows scan with a condition of
         ("NOT (myid.CB9019388E1.ACCT_NB IS NULL)")
         , grouping by field1 ( myid.CB9019388E1.ACCT_NB).  Aggregate
         Intermediate Results are computed locally, then placed in Spool 3.
         The size of Spool 3 is estimated with low confidence to be 3,335
         rows (1,377,355 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.01
         seconds.
      3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 3 (Last Use) by way of
         an all-rows scan into Spool 1 (used to materialize view, derived
         table, table function or table operator D) (all_amps) (compressed
         columns allowed), which is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of
         Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be 3,335 rows (
         737,035 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.01 seconds.
      4) We execute the following steps in parallel.
           1) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 1 (Last Use) by
              way of an all-rows scan with a condition of ("NOT (D.ACCT_NB
              IS NULL)") into Spool 6 (all_amps) (compressed columns
              allowed), which is duplicated on all AMPs.  The size of Spool
              6 is estimated with low confidence to be 4,942,470 rows (
              1,057,688,580 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is
              0.37 seconds.
           2) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from
              ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.DDM_DIM_ACCT_DTL in view
              ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_DIM_ACCT_DTL by way of an all-rows scan
              with no residual conditions into Spool 7 (all_amps)
              (compressed columns allowed), which is built locally on the
              AMPs.  The size of Spool 7 is estimated with high confidence
              to be 176,214,248 rows (7,400,998,416 bytes).  The estimated
              time for this step is 0.73 seconds.
      5) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 6 (Last Use) by way of an
         all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 7 (Last Use) by way of an
         all-rows scan.  Spool 6 and Spool 7 are joined using a single
         partition hash join, with a join condition of (
         "(TRANSLATE((ACCT_NB )USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE)(BIGINT, FORMAT
         '-(19)9'))= (TRANSLATE((ACCT_NB )USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE)(BIGINT,
         FORMAT '-(19)9'))").  The result goes into Spool 8 (all_amps)
         (compressed columns allowed), which is built locally on the AMPs.
         Then we do a SORT to order Spool 8 by the hash code of (
         ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.DDM_DIM_ACCT_DTL.ACCT_DIM_NB).  The size of Spool 8
         is estimated with low confidence to be 3,336 rows (136,776 bytes).
         The estimated time for this step is 0.11 seconds.
      6) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 8 (Last Use) by way of a
         RowHash match scan, which is joined to 74 partitions of
         ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.acct in view ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_FCT_TXN by way of a
         RowHash match scan with a condition of ("(ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.acct in
         view ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_FCT_TXN.TIME_DIM_NB >= DATE '2013-01-01')
         AND (ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.acct.TIME_DIM_NB <= DATE '2019-01-31')").
         Spool 8 and ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.acct are joined using a sliding-window
         merge join, with a join condition of (
         "ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.acct.ACCT_DIM_NB = ACCT_DIM_NB").  The result goes
         into Spool 9 (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed), which is
         built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 9 is estimated with
         low confidence to be 73,453 rows (3,893,009 bytes).  The estimated
         time for this step is 0.33 seconds.
      7) We execute the following steps in parallel.
           1) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 9 (Last Use) by way of
              an all-rows scan, which is joined to rows (DAY_TIME_DIM_NB)
              values (DATE '2019-01-31'), (DATE '2019-01-30'), (DATE
              '2019-01-29'), (DATE '2019-01-28')
 Spool 9 and rows are joined using a product join, with a join
              condition of ("(1=1)").  The result goes into Spool 10
              (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed), which is
              redistributed by the rowkey of (
              ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.acct.TIME_DIM_NB,
              ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.DDM_DIM_ACCT_DTL.ACCT_DIM_NB, DAY_TIME_DIM_NB)
              to all AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to partition Spool 10 by
              rowkey.  The size of Spool 10 is estimated with low
              confidence to be 163,212,566 rows (9,303,116,262 bytes).  The
              estimated time for this step is 1.49 seconds.
           2) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from
              ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.DDM_DIM_TXN in view ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_DIM_TXN
              by way of an all-rows scan with a condition of (
              "ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.DDM_DIM_TXN in view
              ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_DIM_TXN.CS_TXN_CD IN ('387 ',
    '388 ','389
              ','390 ')") into Spool 11 (all_amps) (compressed columns
              allowed), which is duplicated on all AMPs.  Then we do a SORT
              to order Spool 11 by the hash code of (
              ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.DDM_DIM_TXN.TXN_DIM_NB).  The size of Spool 11
              is estimated with low confidence to be 145,236 rows (
              3,630,900 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.00
              seconds.
      8) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from 2222 partitions of
         ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn in view ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_FCT_TXN by way of a
         RowHash match scan with a condition of ("(ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn in
         view ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_FCT_TXN.TIME_DIM_NB >= DATE '2013-01-01')
         AND (((INDEX(UPPER((ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn in view
         ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_FCT_TXN.TXN_DESCRIPTION )),'REVERSAL:'))= 0)
         AND (ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn in view
         ICDW_CB_PRSN_V.DDM_FCT_TXN.TIME_DIM_NB <= DATE '2019-01-31'))"),
         which is joined to Spool 10 (Last Use) by way of a RowHash match
         scan.  ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn and Spool 10 are joined using a
         rowkey-based merge join, with a join condition of ("(ACCT_DIM_NB =
         ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn.ACCT_DIM_NB) AND ((TIME_DIM_NB =
         ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn.TIME_DIM_NB) AND ((TIME_DIM_NB >=
         ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn.DAY_TIME_DIM_NB) AND
         ((ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn.ACCT_DIM_NB = ACCT_DIM_NB) AND
         (DAY_TIME_DIM_NB = ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn.DAY_TIME_DIM_NB ))))").  The
         input table ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn will not be cached in memory, but
         it is eligible for synchronized scanning.  The result goes into
         Spool 12 (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed), which is built
         locally on the AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 12 by the
         hash code of (ICDW_CB_PRSN_T.txn.TXN_DIM_NB).  The size of Spool
         12 is estimated with no confidence to be 1,131,190 rows (
         211,532,530 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 1 minute
         and 44 seconds.
      9) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 11 (Last Use) by way of a
         RowHash match scan, which is joined to Spool 12 (Last Use) by way
         of a RowHash match scan.  Spool 11 and Spool 12 are joined using a
         merge join, with a join condition of ("TXN_DIM_NB = TXN_DIM_NB").
         The result goes into Spool 5 (group_amps), which is built locally
         on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 5 is estimated with no confidence
         to be 35,048 rows (6,904,456 bytes).  The estimated time for this
         step is 0.01 seconds.
     10) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
         in processing the request.
      -> The contents of Spool 5 are sent back to the user as the result of
         statement 1.  The total estimated time is 1 minute and 47 seconds.
```

Comment: That explain doesn't match your Select (the DATEs are quite different). If the actual number of distinct ACCT_NB returned by the Select against your temp table is not close to 3,335 <ou better collect stats on it. And try to avoid the join using CAST, because you loose statistics. What's the actual datatypes of ACCT_NB in both tables?